# How to use sinon on karma?

Tags: karma-runner, sinon, chai

I'm trying to use karma, chai and sinon to test spy.

1. I did:

   ```sh
   npm install karma-sinon --save-dev
   ```
2. I added:

   ```
   frameworks: ['mocha','chai','chai-sinon']
   ```
3. I run:

   ```sh
   karma start
   ```

But I'm getting this error:

```
Error: No provider for "framework:chai-sinon"! (Resolving: framework:chai-sinon)
```

Comment: Can you post your `package.json` file? FWIW it looks like you misspelled `sinon-chai` as `chai-sinon`.. fix the typo and make sure you installed that package as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the same problem by simply adding the chai entry to the Frameworks section of my karma.conf.js script did not solve the problem. Following this [Github Issue](https://github.com/karma-runner/karma/issues/1488) I found that you need to install the karma-cli globally, and everything else can be local and work.

```
 npm install --save-dev karma
 npm install -g karma-cli
 npm install --save-dev karma-phantomjs-launcher karma-chai karma-sinon
```

Answer (score 0):

During going through PluralSight course on Gulp I've come into the same problem.

This issue was due to lack of npm modules that are required. The string that helped me is this:

```
npm install --save-dev karma karma-chai karma-chai-sinon karma-chrome-launcher karma-coverage karma-growl-reporter karma-mocha karma-phantomjs-launcher karma-sinon mocha mocha-clean sinon-chai sinon phantomjs
```

Initially I've misspelled the `karma-chai-sinon` as `karma-chai sinon` so it successfully installed every dependency but resulted in the error.

So please try it. I've got the same error.

Comment: This might be ok for a beginner just trying things out(even then not really) but brute force installing a bunch of packages hoping one works is not a good habit.

Answer (score 0):

Did you add the 'karma-chai-sinon' to your plugins in your karma.conf.js

My plugins looks like this:

```
plugins: [ 'karma-chai-sinon', 'karma-mocha', 'karma-phantomjs-launcher', 'karma-babel-preprocessor' ]
```

Answer (score 0):

I've had the same problem by simply adding the chai entry to the Frameworks section of my karma.conf.js script did not solve the problem, it's the same other frameworks that you point into frameworks array.

Have you installed the "karma-sinon-chai" npm package
Have you tried it?

e.g. `npm install karma-simon-chai --dev-save`